# Sharepoint site - i need to insert data in a list (only this) from a form accessible to all without authentication or invitation

Tags: sharepoint-online

in our SharePoint site, for a feedback project, i need to have a form that is accessible to all (internal or external to our organization and external to SharePoint site so accessible to all from the web) and without autothentication or invitation etc.

Everyone that has the link to this form can access to the form (everyone inside SharePoint and everyone from the web outside SharePoint)
No autothentication , no username and password, must be required. 
It must be a direct link to the form
The anonymous user easily follow the link, a new form appears, insert the data required, submit the form and stop. nothing else
The anonymous user can only use this form to insert data, nothing else and no other resources of the sharepoint

This form in some way must put the data in a specific SharePoint list (called "example")  or in a mirror list that automatically syncronizes the data with the "example" list, after a new record is inserted

I have tried in many way but unfortunately without success
I can't find a solution to give the access to a form to everyone

I can use an html external web site where to create the form i need, but how to connect it with the SharePoint list?

Please, someone can help me
Is There a solution for this request or some workaround to solve

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: If you would like to create a survey kind of functionality. Try Microsoft Forms: https://forms.office.com/ Here, you can create a survey form and all data will be stored within excel file in document library and you can also move them some custom list using Power Automate.

Comment: While you can invite external users, there is currently no way to share something in SharePoint Online with anonymous, non-authenticated users.  But I agree with @DikeshGandhi, if you want to share an input form to anonymous users using the O365 ecosystem, MS Forms is the way to go.  As he alludes to, you can use Power Automate (Flow) to automatically store those responses in a protected SharePoint List, and/or respond to, or manipulate that data.

Comment: i would want to use something more complex than a survey, with a list box and  datepicker. Is possible to do this with Microsoft.forms?

Comment: sorry. i forgot. Thanks a lot before for your help and your answers.

Comment: i have seen the use of Microsoft forms and i will try. thanks

Comment: @sharepoint2000 glad to help you. Kindly mark my answer and upvote it if you find it helpful, so it would helped other readers.

Comment: Hi again. Problem solved. Form for everyone created with microsoft.forms. Flow created between forms and SharePoint. Everytime  one feedback in inserted, in the list is added an item with the info requested. The design of the form unfortunately is not much modifiable…..but this is. Thanks a lot  for the help

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has provided new service called **Microsoft Forms** where you can create different survey forms, quizzes, polls. You can create these forms very easily and without any coding stuffs.

You can create such forms from here: https://forms.microsoft.com

It provides different layouts to create quick forms for surveys, quizzes and polls. You can easily add questions with different input controls like text box, multiple choice, dropdown control, ratings, date time controls, etc.

You can share this form with SharePoint Online licensed users as well as external users or with anonymous users as per your purpose. It will create an excel file to store all your data captured through forms. It also provides charts to visualize and analyze your data. You can also push these data in SharePoint lists using Power Automate flows as well.

Visit [Create a form with Microsoft Forms](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-form-with-microsoft-forms-4ffb64cc-7d5d-402f-b82e-b1d49418fd9d) to create forms in Office 365.

Visit [Microsoft Forms](https://forms.office.com/) to explore more features.